# Windows Azure Cloud Service Access

Tags: azure, neo4j

I have created Virtual Machine Windows 2012 Server on Azure and installed Neo4j on that VM. One of the clod service is created for that by Azure as DNS Name.cloudapp.net I want to know how to access that from my laptop so that I can access Neo4j database from my laptop which is in Azure.

Answer (score 2):

So... you spun up a VM, and are just trying to access it remotely? You need to create public endpoints. For neo4j specifically, you'll want to open ports 7474 and 1337. Here's how I have one of my neo4j servers set up:

[image]

The endpoint names are arbitrary - just for your reference.

Now: You'll need to think about securing these endpoints, once you open them up. Notice the **Manage ACL** item on the bottom of the endpoint list. With that, you can specify allowed/denied IP address ranges. With this, you can filter to only allow traffic from your local office/home's public IP address.

Comment: I have added the endpoint same like you for port 7474, but still not able to access if from local.

Comment: If the neo4j process is running and listening on port 7474, and you opened an endpoint on port 7474, and still can't connect, make sure the firewall in your Windows VM isn't blocking that port. You may need to open it.